# Muxer equivalent library for android OS 4.1.2 and above

Tags: android, video, encoding, h.264, mediamuxer

Currently we are working on a android video editing app. We are facing 2 major problems

We have a byte buffer from which we a H264 stream using media codec.Now we want to create an mp4 video out of  it. We are aware that from 4.3 onwards we  can use media muxer to do so. But we need support older OS like 4.1.2 because it has MediaCodec library. I wanted to know is there any other way to create the mp4 file out of H264 stream without using muxer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the stream creation process is called multiplexing, so in any way you need muxer. it's quite easy to integrate ffmpeg and use mp4 muxer from it